# How to post events and metrics from web app so that it is easy to analyse them?

Tags: firebase, looker-studio, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a web app, that stores data in Firebase and uses a cloud function to log errors to Stackdriver.

I'd like to log usage events somewhere and then see the statistics on a dashboard in Google Data Studio or in other place.

It seems the best option for the storage will be Stackdriver.

How can I submit events and metrics to Stackdriver so that it is easy to analyse them in Data Studio?

Comment: Have you see the Stackdriver monitoring docs here ... https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs  There is also a REST API that can be called from  a web app.  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest

Comment: Why not use Google Analytics to measure the usage events? Is there any specific reason you are choosing Stackdriver?

Comment: @MinhazKazi , I am considering many options. Here is the question on Google analytics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976568/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-a-web-app

Comment: Answered the question there. Once you add Firebase to your Flutter app, it should capture the Google Analytics measurements. You can then directly fetch that data in Data Studio using the Google Analytics Connectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTTP trigger type of Cloud Function for your web client to invoke with the data you would like it to log to StackDriver.

Comment: Can you reference an example how to log events to Stackdriver from function and how to connect to Dtackdriver from Google Data Studio?

Comment: A full explanation of that is off topic for Stack Overflow.  Each one of those products has documentation that should help you construct a final solution.  It sounds like the part you're missing is the API for StackDriver, which should be available for all supported Cloud Functions environments.  Here's the nodejs API: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/stackdriver

Comment: If you get stuck with a specific step when putting all this together, please ask another question showing the code that isn't working the way you expect.